# Как в БД Oracle изменить name?

Tags: oracle

Есть БД Oracle 10.

`Select name from v$database` возвращает `NAME1`.
Как изменить `name` на `NAME2` ?

Comment: Можете более подробно пояснить, что хотите изменить? Отображаемое значение? или результат?

Comment: Хочется изменить имя базы

Comment: Проще по-моему создать новый образ и залить данные дампом.
Если оень нужно - воспользуйтесь утилиткой `nid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал утилиту `NID`.

Соединяемся с БД:

```
>shutdown immediate;
>startup mount;
```

Дальше запускаем в консоли `nid` из стандартной поставки Oracle, в каталоге bin. Подключаемся учетной записью с привилегией SYSDBA

```
>nid TARGET=SYS as SYSDBA DBNAME=new_database_name
```